# assign the value of input type email to another of type email angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to assign an input field of type email to another in angularjs but it is not working. This is my attempt:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="control-group span12">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input name="email" placeholder="" type="email" class="input-block-level" ng-model="email" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="control-group span12">
    <label for="email">Confirm</label>
    <input type="email" name="emailaccess" placeholder="" ng-model="{{id}}" class="input-block-level" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please where is my wrong?

Comment: what it's `{{id}}` ? What do you do?

Comment: Do you mean when I write in first email it should write the same in 2nd input box ?

Comment: Can you explain this `ng-model="{{id}}"`

Comment: if you want to have the same value in the first input in the second you have to replace this `ng-model="{{id}}"` with `ng-model="email"`

Comment: Is a learning curve...

Comment: Forgive me is not my fault...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As angular js had a great feature named two-way binding You need to use the same ng-modal on both controls.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="control-group span12">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input name="email" placeholder="" type="email" class="input-block-level" ng-model="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="control-group span12">
            <label for="email">Confirm</label>
            <input type="email" name="emailaccess" placeholder="" ng-model="email" class="input-block-level" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```